# What happens when AWS EC2 instance exceeds the hibernation limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Understand that AWS EC2 instance can be configurable for hibernation, and that it cannot be hibernated for more than 60 days. What happens when it exceeds 60 days? Will it start up automatically?

Is it the limit also configurable? Or is it determined by AWS to be at 60 days? The AWS documentation for EC2 only state that they do not support keeping an instance hibernated for more than 60 days, and neither does it seem to be configurable... just want to confirm this

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

From the [EC2 FAQ](https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/ec2/faqs/):

> Q: How long can I keep my instance hibernated?

> We do not support keeping an instance hibernated for more than 60 days. You need to resume the instance and go through Stop and Start (without hibernation) if you wish to keep the instance around for a longer duration.

While not very clear, this seems to imply that if the instance is hibernated for a period longer than 60 days then the instance is destroyed.

It also seems that the 60 day time window is not configurable.